# How to check a user's review history?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

A new user suggested an edit to my answer, which had one approval and three rejects (so it was rejected).

However, the edit was fixing an error (I had failed to quote two strings) -- which the three rejects completely failed to notice.  So I'm concerned that the three reviewers who rejected the edit don't know what they are doing, as well as that a new user had a bad experience.  Unfortunately I lack either the privileges, or the knowledge (or likely both), to pursue the matter further.

The edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12196382

Comment: They really should have posted a comment, it's not like you're inactive. The other thing is: most of the time, reviewers are clueless about the code changed in the edit.

Comment: @Laurel:  That's my main concern (clueless reviewers) -- if one is not savvy enough to judge a code change one should skip that review.  How many other incorrect approves/rejects are those three responsible for?

Comment: @EthanFurman There is a lot of criticism surrounding approving suggested code edits, since it's a classic troll move sometimes. If you skip them, there's a chance that the robos will approve it, and further the damage.

Comment: Is it possible the comment "Quoted status names BAD_SPAM and BAD_EGGS" could have better been written as "Custom status names such as BAD_SPAM and BAD_EGGS *must* be quoted"? It is conceivable the rejecters considered them constants (they sure do look like that to me) and thus an "invalid code edit".

Comment: I see you did the edit yourself but only part of it. Was the link suggested in conflict with your intent since you didn't included that?

Comment: @RadLexus: Sure, the edit comment could have been better, but even if it had been would the reviewers known enough to recognize it was correct?  It is my contention that if one is not familiar enough to know what is correct then one shouldn't pass judgement.

Comment: It's definitely unclear whether `BAD_SPAM` and `BAD_EGGS` are constants or if they're misquoted strings. And as you had already included the link to the pypi package (which itself links to the project home page), the home page link doesn't add anything meaningful. I don't think rejecting the edit was a bad decision. I think the best course of action would have been to reject and to leave a comment.

Answer (score 22):

### 1. Overall Suggested Review Stats

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

select total,
       approved,
       round(cast(approved*100 as float)/total ,1) ApprovedPercentage,
       rejected,
       round(cast(rejected*100 as float)/total ,1) RejectedPercentage
 from (
       select count(case when VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 end) approved,
              count(case when VoteTypeId = 3 then 1 end) rejected,
              count(VoteTypeId) total
         from SuggestedEditVotes
        where UserId = @UserId
       ) as grouped;
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/140194/suggested-edit-review-stats
[image: Suggested Review Stats pic]

### 2. Overruled Reviews

To see the suggested edits where a user voted to approve but that were rejected, or vice versa ([by Gilles](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/3240))

```
SELECT
  s.PostId AS [Post Link],
  'site://suggested-edits/' + Cast(s.Id AS VarChar(20)) AS [Suggested Edit],
  'not ' + CASE v.VoteTypeId WHEN 2 THEN 'approved' ELSE 'rejected' END AS [Direction],
  s.CreationDate AS [Date]
FROM SuggestedEditVotes v, SuggestedEdits s
WHERE v.UserId = ##User##
  AND v.SuggestedEditId = s.Id
  AND CASE v.VoteTypeId WHEN 2 THEN s.ApprovalDate ELSE s.RejectionDate END IS NULL
ORDER BY [Date]
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79859/my-overruled-suggested-edit-reviews

**Sample result:**
[image: Overruled reviews]

### 3. Contested Reviews

To see the suggested edits where the decision went in the same direction as a user vote, but there was an opposing vote([by Gilles](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/3240))

```
SELECT
  s.PostId AS [Post Link],
  'site://suggested-edits/' + Cast(s.Id AS VarChar(20)) AS [Suggested Edit],
  CASE v0.VoteTypeId WHEN 2 THEN 'approved' ELSE 'rejected' END AS [Direction],
  s.CreationDate AS [Date]
FROM SuggestedEditVotes v0, SuggestedEditVotes v1, SuggestedEditVotes v2,
     SuggestedEdits s
WHERE v0.UserId = ##User##
  AND v0.SuggestedEditId = s.Id
  AND v1.SuggestedEditId = s.Id
  AND v2.SuggestedEditId = s.Id
  AND v0.VoteTypeId = v1.VoteTypeId
  AND v0.Id <> v1.Id
  AND v0.VoteTypeId <> v2.VoteTypeId
ORDER BY [Date]
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79860/my-contested-suggested-edit-reviews

**Note:** According [to this post](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/314988), Stack Exchange data updated every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC.

Comment: I got divide by zero error with my userid on the 1st query, lol.

Comment: @JohnOdom, Apparently query doesn't have a filter to exclude users with no review history(i.e no of reviews=0)

Answer (score 16):

You can view all reviews done by a user on their [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069707/binaya-regmi?tab=activity&sort=reviews), but this information is hard to digest (there is no way to distinguish between Suggested edits and other queues).

For suggested edits, you can get a summary when you click on the (more) link:

[image]

The reviewers' statistics are not too bad:

[image]